# How to import DB with .sql extension into SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, import

I have a database with `.sql` extension which is exported from server using putty.

How to import this into SQL Server 2012 in Management Studio?

It is not accepting `.sql` as database, throwing error.

If I try to restore using

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'D:\LogFile\accesslog.sql';
```

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.

Please help me with this.

Comment: the credentials you are using don't have CREATE DATABASE permission to create new datebase, try login with sa or ask administrator to add your login to `sysadmin` role.

Comment: Do i need to have this 'Create Database' permission to import database which already contains tables in it .

Comment: "exported from server using PuTTY" makes me think you didn't export from a Windows machine. The .sql extension makes me think it was a MySQL database. I would try to open the .sql file with a text editor: if it contains a lot of INSERT...VALUES it is a MySQL export.

Comment: yes..i exported the file from putty. This is the DB ,not a table. In SQL 2012 it is throwing error,since it is expecting .bacpac extension to import a DB. it contains lot of inserts,create statements

Comment: Yes, you need `CREATE DATABASE` permissions to create a database, even if it was an export from another server. You also need to let us know what type of database you exported from. Was it SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: DB is from MySql.i want to import that into SQL2012. will that be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly restore a MySQL backup to MSSQL. 
What you can do is use tools such as [Microsoft SQL server migration assistant.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313125%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

But those still won't help you if you don't have the proper permissions on the destination server. You'll most likely be creating a database, editing schemas and creating logins and users. Which means you need the sysadmin role.

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/148712/how-to-migrate-from-mysql-to-sql-server-2008) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621682/import-mysql-database-into-a-ms-sql-server).

Answer (score 1):

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx):

> If the database being restored does not exist, the user must have
>   CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE. If the
>   database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the
>   database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always
>   exists).

You're creating a database on your server, regardless of the fact that it already existed on another server, therefore you need `CREATE DATABASE` permissions.